# How to detect edges on an image using numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have the following image: a white cercle in a black background which I want to detect its edges.
my coode seems like this:

```
possible_moves = np.array([[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])

image = np.array(cv2.imread('Example.png'))
image_copy = image.copy()
spots_0 = np.argwhere((image[:, :, 0] == 255) & (image[:, :, 1] == 255) & (image[:, :, 2] == 255))

index = 0
start_time = time.time()

while(True): 
    
    future_Neighbors = np.add(possible_moves, [spots_0[index, 0], spots_0[index, 1]])
    Neighbors_inFrame = (np.argwhere((image[future_Neighbors[:, 0].astype(int), future_Neighbors[:, 1].astype(int), 0] ==  255) & ((image[future_Neighbors[:, 0].astype(int), future_Neighbors[:, 1].astype(int), 1] ==  255)) & ((image[future_Neighbors[:, 0].astype(int), future_Neighbors[:, 1].astype(int), 2] ==  255))))
        
    if len(Neighbors_inFrame) < 8:
        image_copy[future_Neighbors[Neighbors_inFrame[:], 0], future_Neighbors[Neighbors_inFrame[:], 1]] = [0, 0, 255]

    index += 1

    if len(spots_0) == index:  
        break
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

The output of my code gives the following image
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmqHX.png)

I have the following questions:

1)Is there a way to make my code or logic faster??
It takes actually 156ms to treat the hole image and I need to make it at least 10 times faster so that I can treat live images in another step.

2. when it's possible to make it faster. Can this be done with numpy functions ?

Thanks

Comment: I have used [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) to extract boundaries in 3d space before. I don't exactly know what the performance is since my image processing was done offline rather than online so I didn't measure it.

Comment: First I've been using opencv to do the task  but afterwards I wanted to not use predefined functions. thats why I'm aksing if it's possible to implement own logic with numpy

Comment: this smells like morphology operations and boolean operations (dilate - erode) would solve this trivially. -- discard all your code, describe the goal. then you'll get suggested approaches. don't wait for anyone to analyze your code and infer intention. -- the articles [ask] and [mre] can help you ask effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to outline edges.

That can be done using the [morphological gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_gradient)

```py
# im = cv.imread("image.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

edgemap = cv.dilate(im, None) - cv.erode(im, None)

# color them red
im[edgemap != 0] = (0,0,255)
```